# OSWAP ZAP Security Plugin Integration with Jenkins

Tags: security, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-plugins

[image]

I am trying to integrate OSWAP Security Plugin to Jenkins but here in below image i have selected Form based Authentication but In "Script Based Authentication" it is displaying Field is required. Please help me how to Integrate OWSAP With Jenkins

Answer (score 0):

While this is a Jenkins plugin that leverages ZAP, it is not maintained by the ZAP core team. You should reach out to the maintainers of the plugin for support.